# PHP which variables to save in session - and which not to save

Tags: php, session, memcached

I am building a simple webapp and I want to use sessions to keep the user logged in.. I have searched for a long time to find out which variables I should save in a session to keep the user logged in.. Which variables should I not save and Why should I do so.. I have all my session in memcacheD (NB it is with a ´D´ )..

Also I have been looking for an eBook to tell me exactly how to build a secure environment based on sessions.. I have been watching the variables saved by Facebook, but I can't seem to figure out what they are using them for (obviously that's what they want or else it wouldn't be that secure).

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77960/what-to-put-in-a-session-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically Sessions are used to store your logical entity. Don't store a huge amount of data. Keep the data which is really essential and which can be used to retrieve other related information. Example you can store user_id or username in your session and use that to retrieve user related information.

If using e-commerce site You can store cart related data in session like cart_id and so on.

Do Not store:

You should not store secure information like credit card numbers or any other payment details. Also storing user password or other related credentials should not be kept in session.

Regarding Facebook, they basically uses oAuth standards which in turns have a tokenization approach of accesing user related information. They are very safe and popular mode of authentication currently.

Comment: Is it secure enough to just have the username saved? I mean.. there is no way for them to manipulate the session during their active state in the webapp?

Comment: For them means whom the user or the hackers?

Comment: If somebody hacks it I am doomed anyhow, but I actually meant if a username is enough? If I want to retrieve data from SQL - can I simply rely on that when they are logged in I don't have to verify that they still are the one they are? No need to compare their password and username once in a while?

Comment: No need. Once you click login button verify the details and store the user_id or username in session if it successful login. then use that session value across subsequent request in your web app.

Comment: wow.. I am surprised that it is secure enough.. :O - yet so amazingly easy :D

Comment: True :) But it is. There are other issues with session, but if you use it carefully no need to worry. The main thing which I am pointing is session hijacking. You can read about it more here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking

Comment: Wow.. I really learned a lot from that.. I previously used this class http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Session-Managment-System-in-PHP-and-MySQL when I didn't use memcached.. Would it help If I still used this one? Or can't it be used with memcached? - Also I have rewritten it to PDO

Comment: It is safe also. And I think you can use that with memcache. THe purpose of memcache is to store the variable into cache so you don't need to retieve it again and again, you just pass the key and get value. So that should work not a problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't really know what exactly facebook storing.
All you can see is what stored in your cookies.
In most cases cookies receive only session ID, and session itself stored on server, in your case - memcached.
You can store there whatever you need between pages requests.  ID of logged user, probably some cart data, etc

Comment: Would it be too stupid to have an encrypted value of their login data (e-mail, password) and check these data once in a while or what?

Comment: Why would you want to pass password back to client? Encrypted session data via cookies is also used approach, but only when you are sure that you would not pass big amount of data, just User Id, last read article, page before login, etc